# hide/show div using id property with index in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Here Iam facing issue with toggling the div containers. if I click on video button, other divs should close, only if open. because of toggling, if it close already, its opening on click of particular btn.can you help me?
html:

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let doctor of doctordata;let i=index">
      <button appointmentToggle(doctor,'video',i)">video</button>
      <button appointmentToggle(doctor,'clinic',i)">In-clinic</button>
        <div class="row" id="clinicShow{{i}}">
          <button (click)="clinicdetails(i)">clinicName</button>
       </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" id="videoappointmentShow{{i}}">
         videocalendertimeslot
      <div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" id="inclinicappointmentShow{{i}}">
         Incliniccalendertimeslot
      <div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
 index: any;

appointmentToggle(doctor,type,index){
    if(type == 'video'){
    $("#appointmentShow"+index).toggle();
     //here i need to check condition whether its already opened or not, if open, then it should toggle.
     $("#clinicShow"+index).toggle();
   }
   if(type == 'clinic'){
     if(this.index==undefined){
                $("#clinicShow"+index).toggle();
                $("#appointmentShow"+index).toggle();
                this.index=index;
            }else if(this.index == index){
                $("#clinicShow"+index).toggle();
                $("#appointmentShow"+index).toggle();
                index = undefined;
            }else{
                $("#clinicShow"+this.index).toggle();
                $("#clinicShow"+index).toggle();
                $("#appointmentShow"+index).toggle();
                this.index= index;
            }
   }

    clinicdetails(index){
        $("#clinicShow"+index).toggle();
        $("#appointmentShow"+index).toggle();
   }
```

Comment: Isn't the `$` usually a reference to JQuery.  Are you trying to mix JQuery code inside Angular?  Generally not something I'd advise.

Comment: Rather than toggling, have you considered creating a `show()` and `hide()` function, so that elements can be explicitly shown and hidden? Also, can you please create a demo from your "*[mcve]*" code in order that we can compose an answer based on your explicit problem? That way our answers are more useful to you and more informative to future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are going to be a lot of ways to do this.  I'd probably create an array of boolean values to show/hide stuff.

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let doctor of doctordata;let i=index">
      <button appointmentToggle(doctor,'video',i)">video</button>
      <button appointmentToggle(doctor,'clinic',i)">In-clinic</button>
        <div class="row" *ngIf="hideVideo[i]">
          <button (click)="clinicdetails(i)">clinicName</button>
       </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" *ngIf="hideVideo[i]">
         videocalendertimeslot
      <div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" *ngIf="hideClinic[i]">
         Incliniccalendertimeslot
      <div>
</div>
```

Then you're Component file can have a boolean array:

```
hideVideo: boolean[] = [];
hideClinic: boolean[] = []
```

Whenever `doctordata` is initialized also initialize the array:

```
doctordata.forEach(() => { this.hideVideo.push(false);this.hideClinic.push(false);  });
```

You're appointment toggle can be something like this:

```
appointmentToggle(doctor,type,index){
    if(type == 'video'){
      this.hideVideo[index] = !this.hideVideo[index];
      this.hideClinic[index] = !this.hideClinic[index];
   }
}

clinicdetails(index){
      this.hideVideo[index] = !this.hideVideo[index];
      this.hideClinic[index] = !this.hideClinic[index];
}
```

This is incredibly rough and untested.

Edit:  Here is working code.  This version is less rough and untested:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtz8xv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I used the same concept that I used above. However, I think the code would be more ideal if you could introspect your doctordata objects to determine if it should be displayed or not instead of keeping a second array. However, there is also a good argument about not letting display specific logic clutter up your data model objects.

Comment: This stackblitz isnt working, can you share proper one?

Comment: No idea why it isn't working; I think I'll have to re-create it. I'll see what I can do about that.

Comment: @charu Okay, give it a shot now: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtz8xv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @jeffy, Thank you for ur response. It working fine. I implemented with my project.

Comment: @charu Great! Be sure to select this as the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your logic would be simpler if you use show() and hide() instead.
Especially because hiding a hidden element is okay and has no effect...
Look at: [jQuery Effects - Hide and Show](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)
If the first thing you do is hiding the old index (if any) you only need to show the new...

Comment: User should not be mixing JQuery and Angular in the same project.

Answer (score -1):

In the jquery when showing a div and hiding it. I think you don't need an if ... Else condition

Try this code:

```
$(".btn).click(function(){

$("div").toggle();

});
```

Once that .btn is click div will show and if u want to hide it just click the button again

I also try to combine javascript and jquery before but it didn't work out well.

```
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Just add this to your header and you are good to go and it's much easy? Hope this works for you

Comment: Just downvoting because the OP should not be mixing JQuery and Angular in the same app.